# Connecting ActiveMQ consumer running 5.8 with ActiveMQ server running 5.5

Tags: java, activemq-classic, legacy

I'm having some difficulties with ActiveMQ. I have a legacy ActiveMQ server set up using version 5.5. I also have a newer messaging consumer running with version 5.8 that needs to consume messages from the legacy server. When I try to create a queue within the legacy server, I get no error messages, but no queue gets created either. I thought maybe there are some JMS options that are not supported with the older server, but I boiled down the JMS options to just the 'timeout=x' with no luck.

Is there any reason ActiveMQ 5.5 can not interact with 5.8?

Comment: The only reason it would not work is if you attempt to use features that are only available in 5.8 on.  When you say you are "creating a queue" what do you mean by this exactly?  Has this client ever worked? Are you using a failover URI? (failover:(urls))

Comment: Yes I'm using failovers. The client does indeed work on a newer 5.8 server. I'm doing some digging to find out what changed between 5.5 and 5.8 and check the code for these. The issue with that though, is that I would expect some sort of error to propagate telling me something went wrong and I get nothing. It just stalls out attempting to connect. When I say create a queue, I mean set up a messaging consumer on the ActiveMQ server.

Comment: Remove the failover URI and just try the connection.  Fail-over sometimes will suppress some errors.  This does not mean you cannot use failover, but it may show you the errors you expect to see.  You also may get some clues on the broker side as to what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

No - there is no particular reason an ActiveMQ v5.5 server cannot interact with a v5.8 client. Of course it is an untested scenario and you'd forego bug fixes and new features but it should work. Always upgrade if you can. :)